# The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format Xcode 11

Tags: php, json, swift, xcode

I'm getting this error message.

"The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format"

The post request works in PostMan so the error must be in my code and not in my DB.

I tried a couple of things but I'm a beginner and I'm kind of stuck here...

I've json data that that look like this

```
{  "error":1, "NumUser":"179", "cFirstname":"test", "cEmail":"a@a.com", "cPassword":"$2y$10$uV.YUtyfyiDzUT/2HYS/dOmIg7vNVPrwNhcmbg5iFvHlVi1rEThuC"  }
```

I take data from the json using swift

```
//
//  NetworkingService.swift
//  Database Login
//
//  Created by Kyle Lee on 2/17/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Kilo Loco. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation

enum MyResult<T, E: Error> {

    case success(T)
    case failure(E)
}

class NetworkingService {

    let baseUrl = "https://zzzway.com/appMango"

    func handleResponse(for request: URLRequest,
                        completion: @escaping (Result<User, Error>) -> Void) {

        let session = URLSession.shared

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                guard let unwrappedResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                    completion(.failure(NetworkingError.badResponse))
                    return
                }

                print(unwrappedResponse.statusCode)

                switch unwrappedResponse.statusCode {

                case 200 ..< 300:
                    print("success")

                default:
                    print("failure")
                }

                if let unwrappedError = error {
                    completion(.failure(unwrappedError))
                    return
                }

                if let unwrappedData = data {

                    do {
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: unwrappedData, options: [])
                        print(json)

                        if let user = try? JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: unwrappedData) {
                            completion(.success(user))

                        } else {
                            let errorResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(ErrorResponse.self, from: unwrappedData)
                            completion(.failure(errorResponse))
                        }

                    } catch {
                        completion(.failure(error))
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }

    func request(endpoint: String,
                 parameters: [String: Any],
                 completion: @escaping (Result<User, Error>) -> Void) {

        guard let url = URL(string: baseUrl) else {
            completion(.failure(NetworkingError.badUrl))
            return
        }

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)

        var components = URLComponents()

        var queryItems = [URLQueryItem]()

        for (key, value) in parameters {

            let queryItem = URLQueryItem(name: key, value: String(describing: value))
            queryItems.append(queryItem)
        }

        components.queryItems = queryItems

        // username=kiloloco&password=pass123
        let queryItemData = components.query?.data(using: .utf8)

        request.httpBody = queryItemData
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        handleResponse(for: request, completion: completion)
    }

    func request(endpoint: String,
                 loginObject: Login,
                 completion: @escaping (Result<User, Error>) -> Void) {

        guard let url = URL(string: baseUrl) else {
            completion(.failure(NetworkingError.badUrl))
            return
        }

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)

        do {
            let loginData = try JSONEncoder().encode(loginObject)
            request.httpBody = loginData

        } catch {
            completion(.failure(NetworkingError.badEncoding))
        }

        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        handleResponse(for: request, completion: completion)
    }


}

enum NetworkingError: Error {
    case badUrl
    case badResponse
    case badEncoding
}
```

```
//
//  LoginViewController.swift
//  Database Login
//
//  Created by Kyle Lee on 2/17/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Kilo Loco. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UITableViewController {

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle { return .lightContent }

    @IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

    let alertService = AlertService()
    let networkingService = NetworkingService()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
    }

    @IBAction func didTapLoginButton() {

        guard
            let cEmail = usernameTextField.text,
            let cPassword = passwordTextField.text,
            let Connecter:String="Connecter"
            else { return }


//        formDataRequest(username: username, password: password)

        jsonRequest(cEmail: cEmail, cPassword: cPassword, Connecter: Connecter)
    }

    func formDataRequest(cEmail: String, cPassword: String, Connecter: String) {
        let parameters = ["email": cEmail,
                          "password": cPassword,
                          "loginbutton": Connecter]

        networkingService.request(endpoint: "/login.php", parameters: parameters) { [weak self] (result) in

            switch result {

            case .success(let user): self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSegue", sender: user)

            case.failure(let error):

                guard let alert = self?.alertService.alert(message: error.localizedDescription) else { return }
                self?.present(alert, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }

    func jsonRequest(cEmail: String, cPassword: String, Connecter: String) {

        let login = Login(cEmail: cEmail, cPassword: cPassword, Connecter: Connecter)

        networkingService.request(endpoint: "/login.php", loginObject: login) { [weak self] (result) in

            switch result {

            case .success(let user): self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSegue", sender: user)

            case.failure(let error):

                guard let alert = self?.alertService.alert(message: error.localizedDescription) else { return }
                self?.present(alert, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if let mainAppVC = segue.destination as? MainAppViewController, let user = sender as? User {

            mainAppVC.user = user
        }
    }
}
```

```
import Foundation

struct User: Decodable {

    let error:Int
    let NumUser: Int
    let cFirstname: String
    let cEmail: String
    let cPassword: String

}
```

Comment: Can you show your **User Model**. You are getting this error because of that.

Comment: just added it at the end

Comment: **NumUser** in your model is **Int** but the response you have shared above it's coming in **String** that's why you are getting this issue because `JsonDecoder` is unable to parse it. I hope you got my point.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand... I'm a beginner, do I need to change something else than the User Model?

Comment: As mentioned by @HammerClass `NumUser` type should be `String`. But you have another issue as well related to `JSON` structure. You are getting an invalid `JSON`, what you can do is print data returned from the api as `print(String(data: unwrappedData, encoding: .utf8)! )` and validate in any json [validator](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu) or include in your question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58515483/edit).

Comment: Just verified and my json is all good. What else could it be?

Answer (score 1):

If you still have the problem

change:

```
struct User: Decodable {

    let error:Int
    let NumUser: Int
    let cFirstname: String
    let cEmail: String
    let cPassword: String

}
```

to:

```
struct User: Decodable {

    let error:Int
    let NumUser: String
    let cFirstname: String
    let cEmail: String
    let cPassword: String

}
```

This is how your JSON is looking and it has to match your model.:

```
{
    "error": Int,
    "NumUser": String,
    "cFirstname": String,
    "cEmail": String,
    "cPassword": String
}
```

Also in your jsondecoder `do catch` you will get an error in the `catch` that will tell you something similar to:

```
Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.String, 
Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "NumUser", 
intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Int but found an String 
instead.", underlyingError: nil)))
```

Which actually reveals what is wrong. You can show it by `print(error.localizedDescription)` or if you stop with a breakpoint you can use `po error.localizedDescription` in the console

Comment: thankyou, I changed my User Struct. I also printed the error in the console but the error is the same as before, nothing more specific. "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format"

Comment: I've been debugging this for awhile. I didn't know it was something so simple lol

Answer (score 0):

Use this model and you will get your response there is small mistake in your model compare your model with this one and you will find out.

```
struct User: Codable {
let error: Int?
let numUser, cFirstname, cEmail, cPassword: String?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case error
    case numUser = "NumUser"
    case cFirstname, cEmail, cPassword
}
```

}